# How to get back Terminal ( Command History + Scrollback ) after manualy quitting the Terminal app?

Tags: macos, terminal, buffer

Sometimes when I update anything from App store and my mackbook pro restarts , when I log in back I found all applications status saved includes my terminal commands history+output darkened in grey color.

My problem , When I do manual restart or quitting the Terminal app , I re-open it with nothing at all !

How Can I get all my commands history+output darkened as a grey text when I manually quit the Terminal app ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have a mac, but since OSX is a flavor of linux (more or less) have you tried the `history` command?

Comment: @DavidWilkins I know about this command , but it brings only the commands without the output ( results ), Thanks !

Comment: Ahh I missed the output part...  Have you taken a look at http://superuser.com/questions/186805/terminal-output-history ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution should be found here  superuser.com/questions/186805/terminal-output-history
the program is called `byobu`

Adding the answer here for credit